# does pg_partman support list or hash partitions

Tags: postgresql

Going through the documentation of pg_partman, looks like it supports partition maintenance only for range partition with either time series or serial values (numbers). Does it support list or hash partitions? Don't think it does but wanted to check if anybody used it in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make much sense to have automatic partition creation for hash partitioning. You have to create all partitions immediately, and you cannot add more partitions later on.

Automatic partition creation for list partitioning only makes sense if a partition should be created based on rows that should be inserted. But I don't think that pg_partman provides functionality for that.

The only case where you can predict when a new partition has to be created is range partitioning on dates or timestamps.

Comment: Agree, so it doesn't support right. I am looking for converting non partitioned to partioned tables for list and hash without downtime. Something similar to the online conversion process supported by pgpartman.

Comment: You could have mentioned that in the question, that would have been useful. The only way I know to convert to a partitioned table wil little downtime is logical replication.

Comment: you could do that with pg_partman for range partitions, but i dont see support for list and hash partitions in pg_partman, I just wanted to confirm that and that was my question.

Comment: What I missed in your question was that you wanted to *convert* tables from non-partitioned to partitioned ones. But don't worry.